# C# Resources - How to find actual language file in use?

Tags: c#, resources

I have a number resx files as follows,

Resources-es-ES.resx
Resources-es.resx
Resources.resx (english defaults)

They are compiled into an assembly and I use them for localising my web pages by simply referring to Resources.Ok for example.  My question is whether there is a way to find out the "rendered culture", e.g. if I come into the site with my CurrentUICulture set to "fr-fr" for example it will fall back to using the English resources and I'm wondering how to get that information to help me with some JavaScript localisation.

Comment: I'm looking for something server side to help find the correct url for a js file. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work much with localization but reading your question I'd just put a key in each of the .resx files that contains the CultureInfo code for that particular file that I could feed the Javascript with.

Comment: I like this, simple but should work a treat for my particular problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Luckily .NET has built-in javascript object with culture information. Assuming you've got ScriptManager on page (I think you need it..), you can use this:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
   var culture = Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
   alert(culture.name); //shows en-GB etc
</script>
```

**Edit**:
You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397445.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try the javascript on this page:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Page/GetCulturedeDEidIDC.htm